# Consulta SQL com joins entre 3 tabelas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo as seguintes tabelas:

- A (`idA`, `nome`, `valor`)
- B (`id`, `idA`, `nome`, `valor`)
- C (`id`, `idA`, `nome`, `valor`)

Portanto, tenho as seguintes relações A -> B e A -> C

Eu preciso gerar uma consulta que retorne pra mim todos os registros de A que estão na tabela C MAS que não estejam na tabela B.

Alguma dica de como poder solucionar este problema ?

Eu sei desenvolver o INNER JOIN quando tenho que relacionar mais de uma tabela porém nessa situação que mencionei fiquei em dúvida realmente sobre como resolver.

Comment: olá, veja se isso ajuda: https://codingstatus.com/sql-join-3-tables/

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a cláusula [NOT IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/logical/in-not-in)
Desta forma a consulta resultante ficaria o seguinte:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a
INNER JOIN c ON a.idA = c.idA 
where a.idA NOT IN (SELECT id FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.idA = b.idA);
```

Outra maneira é utilizando a cláusula `EXCEPT` (que é equivalente à operação [subtração de conjunto](https://www.colegioweb.com.br/conjuntos/subtracao.html), a maneira acima também é equivalente à operação de diferença de conjuntos):

```
SELECT a.* FROM a
INNER JOIN c ON a.idA = c.idA 
EXCEPT SELECT a.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.idA = b.idA;
```

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Muito obrigado Dani pela ajuda, consegui resolver graças a sua resposta
Grato ;)